# Formula to get the maximum value in alphabetical order within a subset of a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns in my Excel tab. One defines the status of a task and another gives the expected time needed to complete.

[image]

I need to calculate, for those rows where Status is not Completed, the longest time frame. In this case `1 - 3 hours`. To facilitate this I have added letters to the beginning of the time frames, so that the exercise is to get the maximum value in alphabetical order (for the rows having status <> "Completed").

Comment: what value? time? or another column you are not showing?

Comment: The question is pretty clear... just don't stop at the title.

Comment: It really isn't a clear question.. honestly it looks like you've already alphabetized your sheet for sorting, so what is left to be done exactly?

Comment: Ook guys! I'll edit the questtion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Structured Table References then I'll have to leave it to you to translate this solution into the necessary syntax if you so desire (in any case, it will still work as it stands).

Assuming your table is in A1:B10 (with headers in row 1):

`=IF(COUNTIF(B2:B10,"<>Completed"),LOOKUP(1,0/FREQUENCY(0,1/(1+(B2:B10<>"Completed")*COUNTIF(A2:A10,"<="&A2:A10))),A2:A10),"No Solution")`

Regards

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works except for when the column status is "Completed for every row. In this case it shows just the value in the top row.

Comment: Good spot. Apologies. Have amended with an additional clause.